# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud' When deploying Streamlit App to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, streamlit

I created a python streamlit app in my local , I have the following imports in my code ;

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import streamlit as st
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

after that I commanded for a requirements.txt file ,  it created following ;

```
pandas==1.3.2
numpy==1.21.2
plotly==5.2.1
geopandas==0.9.0
requests==2.26.0
streamlit==0.86.0
matplotlib==3.4.3
protobuf==3.17.3
```

In local ,it works very well.
I have deployed my app to heroku succesfully but when I run the app it says ;

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'

I am using bigquery queries in my code and taking query results with service_account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding followings to my requirements.txt ;

```
google.cloud < 0.34.0
google.cloud.bigquery < 2.24.0
google.cloud.core < 1.7.2
google.auth < 1.34.0
google.resumable.media < 1.3.3
google.api.core < 1.31.1
```

The google-cloud-bigquery is not enough itself also it depends on the followings;

```
google-cloud-core  
google-auth  
google.resumable.media  
google.api.core
```

Answer (score 0):

To access bigquery, you need to add the library to your `requirements.txt` file:

`pip install google-cloud-bigquery`

Comment: Thanks your advise :)

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer if it helped you.

Comment: this helped me a little bit  , the upper one solved exactly my problem but thanks again.